# Using cables, how do I mirror my macbook's screen onto an iPhone screen?

Tags: macos, ios, hdmi

It's nice that I can mirror my iPhone onto my Macbook using a simple lighting to USB-whatever cable, then open Quicktime but what about the inverse of this? I want to simply record my mac's screen booting up into recovery, or record it in places where you usually wouldn't be able to open up Quicktime and record your entire screen.

Do I need to use an HDMI cable from my mac going into an external monitor, then record the monitor or can I use a [dongle](https://store.storeimages.cdn-apple.com/4982/as-images.apple.com/is/MD826?wid=2000&hei=2000&fmt=jpeg&qlt=80&.v=1566858915905) and trick my mac into sending HDMI input to my phone? Simply put, it's like recording the screen of a virtual machine.

I have a `Macbook18,3` running `macOS 12.1` and an iPhone 11 running iOS 15.1. If you happen to bring up third party apps, try and keep it free

Answer (score 0):

The iPhone in itself is not able to record HDMI. The linked dongle is for outputting HDMI from an iPhone - it will not be able to record HDMI for you.

The alternative you mentioned is the simplest way to do this - simply display the HDMI output on a monitor, and use the iPhone's camera to make a video of the monitor.

If you really want to record HDMI on the iPhone, you need a USB video capture device plugged into a [the Lightning to USB 3 Camera Adapter](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MK0W2AM/A/lightning-to-usb-3-camera-adapter). However, you need to select a suitable [video capture device](https://www.febon.net/products/icapture), as not all video capture devices work on the iPhone.